# How to make a background slideshow for the nav>ul tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slideshow

I want to change the image background every few seconds.
banner1 banner2 ...
my css code :

```
nav>ul{
    width: 529px;
    height: 529px;
    background: url(../images/banner1.png) center no-repeat;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    margin: -216px -260px;
    left: 50%;
    z-index: 50;
}
```

html code :

```
<nav>
<ul>
anything
</ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this jQuery plugin to make a background slideshow. It will stretch any image to fit the container element.

You only have to include the plugin and write a script similar to this:

```
<script>
$(".container-element-class").backstretch([
      "path-to-your/image1.jpg"
    , "path-to-your/image2.jpg"
    , "path-to-your/image3.jpg"
  ], {duration: 3000, fade: 750});
</script>
```

http://srobbin.com/jquery-plugins/backstretch/